# Entity Sent to Rules Checker Doesn't include All Fields

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

In my controller I'm saving a password entity and afterwards I update the date fields in the entity before I save. I created a Validation Rule as an Application Rule as explained here https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/validation.html#using-validation-as-application-rules to validate the entity after it was modified with a custom function.

Unfortunately it is validating twice. The first time works as expected after patchentity but the second time fails because all fields are not included in the entity that is sent to ruleschecker. The only fields in the entity sent to ruleschecker are the two date fields I most recently updated. How can I resend all fields in the entity to ruleschecker? Or force the errors from the patchentity validation to display at save.

**CONTROLLER**

```
$password = $this->Passwords->patchEntity($password, $this->request->getData());

// Convert Dates to SQL format
$password->effective_on = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strtotime($this->request->getData('effective_on')));
$password->effective_until = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strtotime($this->request->getData('effective_until')));

if (! $this->Passwords->save($password)) {
...
```

**RULES**

```
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules): RulesChecker
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['user_id'], 'Users'));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['environment_id'], 'Environments'));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['rule_type_id'], 'RuleTypes'));

        // Add validation rules
        $rules->add(function($entity) {
                $data = $entity->extract($this->getSchema()->columns(), true);
                $validator = $this->getValidator('default');
                $errors = $validator->validate($data, $entity->isNew());
                $entity->setErrors($errors);

                return empty($errors);
        });

        return $rules;
```

Comment: Why are you even doing those two manual assignments. Those fields should be set already from the patch call. And if they're the only reason you're doing the awkward validation in the rules, then fixing that will solve all the problems and make all your code cleaner and more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I'm currently upgrading old code that someone else implemented. I was able to change the format of the date fields in beforeMarshal and not have to use the Validation Rule as an Application Rule after all.

Comment: Good to hear. This will certainly be an overall better result for you.